# android change tab indicator style

Tags: android, android-styles

This is my style

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/customActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
<style name="customActionBarTabStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">

        <!-- tab indicator -->
        <item name="android:background">#ac0910</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
    </style>
```

I got this result:
[image]
but if i changed my xml to this:
[image]

```
    <!-- tab indicator -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator</item>
</style>
```

I got this result:

This is my @drawable/actionbar_tab_indicator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS NOT PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused" />


<!-- STATES WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED -->

    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />

    <!-- Focused states (such as when focused with a d-pad or mouse hover) -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed" />
</selector>
```

#### the most important part is

@drawable/tab_selected_pressed
@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed
@drawable/tab_selected_pressed
...

are images like rectange and fill in colors. this is what i **though** is the indicator

Answer (score 1):

create a custom layout in the xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tab_button_drawable"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" > <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@drawable/text_navigator_color_drawable"
    android:textSize="14dp" /></LinearLayout>
```

and create a method which will return a custom view than  define as this after defining the tab view

```
public View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,
            null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab_text_view);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

`tabSpec.setIndicator(createTabView(tabHost.getContext(),
                        tabWidgetTextView.getText().toString()));`